# Nodejs readable.read() return null

Tags: node.js

I want read bytes from a file, here is the sample code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var stream= fs.createReadStream('./lib');
console.log(stream.read(10));
```

return null.

I think it's because `read()` method directly get data from the inner buffer. If the buffer has not enough data, the `null` is returned. The `read()` method is a sync call, no callback being passed, so that design makes sense.
However I don't know when the inner buffer can have enough data so that my `read()` call can return data since it's paused mode now?

Update1:

event `readable` is a good way to get started. But if I want to read a large file, and the read count > `65536`, null will return.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var stream = fs.createReadStream('./lib');
stream.on('readable', function () {
    var buffer = stream.read(65537);
    console.log(buffer.length);

});
```

What I want exactly is stream.read() can always return data till the EOF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wait for the `readable` event to fire before trying to read:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var stream= fs.createReadStream('./lib');
stream.on('readable', function () {
  var buffer = stream.read(10);
  if (buffer) {
    console.log(buffer.toString());
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a good point. I updated my post and please take a look. The `readable` event seems couldn't perfectly solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks, this is the most rare information if one is searching to convert file-stream to a buffer. I have gone through many similar topics but I couldn't find this type of conversion. This post saved my day.

Comment: I had an (unresearched) error where i got unexpected bytes back when i used a `stream.on('readable'...)` function which disappeared  when I switched to await (`await new Promise((accept, reject) => { input.on('readable', () => accept(null)); })`). So if you run into mystery bytes, try `await`.

Answer (score 7):

According to the official [document](http://nodejs.cn/doc/node/stream.html#stream_event_readable):

> Once the internal buffer is drained, a 'readable' event will fire
>   again when more data is available.

I can use async/await so that readable.read() can always return data as long as not at the EOF.

```
let rs = fs.createReadStream('./resources/1.gif');

async function readable(): Promise<{}> {
    return new Promise(r => rs.on('readable', r));
}

async function readBytes(num: number = 0): Promise<Buffer> {
    let buf = rs.read(num);
    if (buf) {
        return new Promise<Buffer>(r => r(buf));
    }
    else {
        return new Promise<Buffer>(r => {
            this.readable().then(() => {
                this.readBytes(num).then(b => r(b));
            });
        });
    }
}

async function main() {
    console.log('begin');
    console.log((await readBytes(10)).length);
    console.log((await readBytes(65535)).length);
    console.log((await readBytes(100000)).length);
    console.log((await readBytes(10)).length);
    console.log('end');
}

main();
```

Outputs:

```
begin
10
65535
100000
10
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'd been going round in circles for ages and the key things I learned from this were:

(a) The `readable` event fires each time there is new data. I had read the spec as saying there was one `readable` when data was ready, and another at the same time as `end`. Missing that key sentence threw me right off.

(b) This solution is very neat in how it attaches the `readable` listener just when needed, keeping things very simple.

One minor tweak to watch out for if you adopt this code--the default value for `read()` is `undefined` rather than `0`.

Comment: I found this code useful, so I wanted to thank the person who answered. One thing to note with this answer that is not mentioned though is that you are stacking event listeners. You need to remove the previous `readable` listener before adding a new one or you're gonna get a `MaxListenersExceededWarning` and eventually some bad behavior. `rs.removeAllListeners('readable');` before adding the new `readable` listener should do it.

Comment: Or just use `once` instead of `on` to register a one-time listener. Also no need to wrap `buf` in a Promise resolving to the value of `buf` -- an `async` function will wrap the returned value in a promise if the value returned isn't one already, so you can just use `if(buf) return buf;`.

Comment: Kudos to BartMao for this answer! Additionally it is important to halt `readBytes` when there is no more data in file because trying to read more bytes then available in file will result to endless loop.
I solved it by checking if `rs.readableLength` increased after waiting for `readable` event.

Answer (score 1):

If I may quote from the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream('./lib');
stream.on('readable', () => {
   let chunk;
   while (null !== (chunk = stream.read())) {
      console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Streams read data in chunks for processing.  If you just want to get the entire contents of the file you should use `fs.readFile()`.

```
fs.readFile(FILENAME, (err, data) => {
    console.log(Buffer.isBuffer(data));
    console.log(data.length);
})
```

A stream, on the other hand, will emit a `data` event whenever it has data for you.  By default, the `highWaterMark` for this stream is 64K.

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(FILENAME);
var results = []

stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
    // For text files chunk is string
    // for binary files chunk is an instance of Buffer

    // do something with this chunk...

    results.push(`Chunk ${results.length} OK`)
});

stream.on('end', function() {
    console.log(results);
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your code works perfectly on flowing mode, but I want to read specified length of bytes each time on paused mode, how can I make it? In your case, I can only declare another buffer outside the event handler to do it.

Comment: Perhaps you should post some code of what you are actually trying to do?  Where are you calling .read() from?

Comment: I want to parse the format of the file. Use gif file as an example, first 3 bytes represents file header, next 3 represents version, then followed by many different data blocks with unfixed sizes. My current Idea is calling .read(3), .read(3), .read(xx)... individually. If one read(xx) encounter the end of the buffer(65536 as the default), that call will return null.

Comment: Take a look at this [file](https://github.com/bartmao/LearnEverything/blob/master/app.js) at github if it helps.That's what I'm doing.